# Why does simply opening a file make VS think I've made changes?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

It doesn't happen all the time, with every file, but some times when I open I file I immedaitely see the asterisk show up in the tabs, as if I've made changes to a file when I haven't.

Moving to a new application at work where this one solution has over 100 projects, skimming through the code to try and get familiar with it, it's really annoying constantly getting bombarded asking if i want to save/discard my changes when I haven't made any.

Just wondering if there's a way to prevent it / what causes it.

Comment: It could be an extension/add-on you have installed. It may format document, tabify, etc. when opening a document. Try opening VS Cmd Line and doing `devenv /SafeMode` and see if it still occurs to rule this out or not.

Comment: First of all, go to Tools->Options->Source Control->Environment and make sure than your saving and editing are set to "Prompt for check out" and "Allow checked-in items to be edited" is unchecked. And generally, all check boxes are unchecked